# Cannot associate .hpp, .cpp extensions with visual studio 2017RC in Windows 10

Tags: c++, qt, file-association, visual-studio-2017

You know my question. Here is the longer version. Downloaded 2017RC, it took me a day to set it up to work with UCRT, CMake, Google test and all the goodies. Then I tried to associate the usual `hpp, h, cpp` extensions two ways:

1. `Control panel -> Default Programs -> Set Default Programs`, choose Visual Studio 2017RC and then `-> Set Program Associations` where all the possible extensions that can be handled by this program are listed. None of the usual C++ extensions are listed.
2. Right click on a `.cpp` file, `Open with`, visual studio 2017 RC doesn't show up in the apps list, hunt it down and click on it. A dialog box pops up saying that *The program you have chosen cannot be associated with this file type*.

FYI, currently all the c, C++ extensions are associated with Qt. Am I to think that RCs are not expected to have this feature? Or is it some other sub-program within VS, with which the association should be made? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem for Visual Studio 2015. The answer here is a good starting point:

https://superuser.com/questions/977271/windows-10-visual-studio-2015-xaml-file-association

Specifically, modifying "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.cpp". I changed the (Default) String value to VisualStudio.cs.14.0 and it now opens .cpp files in Visual Studio 2015.

You would have to use whatever version Microsoft has for Visual Studio 17. Take a look at an existing working file extension to see what it uses.

As usual, backup everything before messing around in the Windows registry.

For what it's worth, Microsoft appears to have fixed this bug, and will apparently be releasing the fix in the next release:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/3122/vc-file-association-not-correct.html